# How to create a column based on values in the rows below the row in a different column

Tags: r, rows, dplyr

I have a dataset like this

```
data <- data.frame(A = c(3,12,3,5,6,3,9,134,13,23))
```

I want to use the A row values to create a new column B that's based on one row below A.
Like this:

```
     A   B
1    3  12
2   12   3
3    3   5
4    5   6
5    6   3
6    3   9
7    9 134
8  134  13
9   13  23
10  23  NA
```

I've tried using dplyr (i.e. mutate), but I'm a little stumped.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lead`

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
           mutate(B = lead(A))
data
#     A   B
#1    3  12
#2   12   3
#3    3   5
#4    5   6
#5    6   3
#6    3   9
#7    9 134
#8  134  13
#9   13  23
#10  23  NA
```

---

Or with `base R` by removing the first element of 'A' and appending `NA` at the end

```
data$B <- c(data$A[-1], NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tail` :

```
data$B <- c(tail(data$A, -1), NA)
data
#     A   B
#1    3  12
#2   12   3
#3    3   5
#4    5   6
#5    6   3
#6    3   9
#7    9 134
#8  134  13
#9   13  23
#10  23  NA
```